# Where to put code in Laravel (for background processing)

Tags: laravel

I am looking for some advice about where to place some code so it makes sense within the Laravel framework directory structure and class types.

My question is:

Assume I have three models EmployeeSchedule, EmployeeTimeInTimeOut and EmployeeLate. I have a resource controller that stores a schedule as a start time and stop time in EmployeeSchedule. A second resource controller allows a timestamp to be recorded in EmployeeTimeInTimeOut.

When an entry is made into EmployeeTimeInTimeOut, I want to check it against the start time in EmployeeSchedule and if the employee is late, the number of minutes late is added as an entry in EmployeeLate.

All example code I can see on the internet places the code to conditionally add an entry to EmployeeLate in the store() method of the EmployeeTimeInTimeOut controller.

The challenge that is that this is an oversimplified example. There needs to be lots of checks that occur and other summary tables updated. For example, every time EmployeeTimeInTimeOut is added or deleted, we need to recalculate the total monthly hours worked and update that value in a summary table. All these checks will take too long for this to occur in the store() method as it will create slow loading page for the user after they add a time in/out.

Just as we do when we avoid end-user delays and use a queued job to send an email, I am thinking I need to listen for an add/delete/update of either EmployeeTimeInTimeOut or EmployeeSchedule and then dispatch a ProcessShiftJob that does all the work in the background.

In ProcessShiftJob, should I be calling a model function such as EmployeeTimeInTimeOut::checkForNeedToAndAddLatePlusOtherThings()

or should I put it all in a helper BackgroundProcessingHelper::checkForNeedToAndAddLatePlusOtherThings(EmployeeTimeInTimeOut $e)

or should I be using something like \App\Service\BackgroundTimesheetProcessing and do something like
$service->checkForNeedToAndAddLatePlusOtherThings(EmployeeTimeInTimeOut $e);

I am a bit lost and hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Google and viewing a lot of open-source repositories on Github, does not seem to be getting me anywhere.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.